# "Gaza tamen aliquoties occiput vertit"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, new-latin

In a [footnote](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZVBfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22Ad%20Brechma,%20brechma,%20tis;%20sive%20bregma,%20pars%20anterior%20capitis%22&source=bl&ots=mUGK1D82xG&sig=ACfU3U3X0mu1SDHHdIhwvDBw07QbA1U9Jg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYj_-L8aHsAhURM-wKHUV3AucQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Ad%20Brechma%2C%20brechma%2C%20tis%3B%20sive%20bregma%2C%20pars%20anterior%20capitis%22&f=false) of Vives' *Dialogs* (for the word "Ad brechma"):

> Ad Brechma, brechma, tis; sive bregma, pars anterior capitis, synciput a Breco Graeco, quod est pluo, et irrigo; haec enim pars maxime humida, et tenera esse solet praecipue infantibus: Gaza tamen aliquoties occiput vertit.

It is understood that *brechma* is the forehead where we humans used to sweat. Yet I have 3 distinct questions (in order of importance) about this passage:

1. what is "Gaza tamen aliquoties occiput vertit", my guess Gaza is [Theodorus Gaza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodorus_Gaza) (fits the timeline), but I am puzzled with respect to "aliquoties occiput vertit" — "Gaza reversed the back-head several times"(?) [attributed the opposite meaning?]
2. what is *tis* in "Ad Brechma, brechma, tis"?
3. What is the Greek word "Breco" that is the source of our *brechma*. [Other version](https://books.google.com/books?id=eoDfjzmd_FYC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=pars%20anterior%20capitis,%20synciput%20a%20verbo&source=bl&ots=7wemK7VRv-&sig=ACfU3U03gavJxfMrmZchuKsbVtHeVd0XbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbvL3-86HsAhWICewKHXBAC18Q6AEwA3oECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=pars%20anterior%20capitis%2C%20synciput%20a%20verbo&f=false) renders this footnote as "synciput a *verbo* Graeco" (instead "synciput a *Breco* Graeco"), but I suspect the correct reading is indeed *Breco*.

**Edit:**

I was able to locate the Greek word, which is [βρέχω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%87%CF%89) (I wet, rain) as said in the footnote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order of certainty:

**2.** As this is essentially a dictionary entry, explaining a word, I think "Ad Brechma, brechma, tis" indicates the declension.
The *-tis* is the genitive ending, so this is a Greek style third declension neuter.
Modern dictionaries could write this as "*brechma, brechmatis*" or "*brechma, -tis*".
So the missing bit that helps parsing this correctly is the dash before *tis*.

**1.** I am less sure about this one, but it seems possible that here *vertere* means "to translate".
If you read the verb like this, the sentence says: "Gaza sometimes translates this as *occiput*."

**3.** I think the full version would be "*synciput* a verbo Graeco *breco*", "*synciput* from the Greek word *breco*".
Leaving out the explicit word *verbo* is not a big surprise, nor is a later editor adding it in.
Why they would leave out *breco* beats me; perhaps they thought it was a misprint for *verbo*?
Unfortunately I don't know nearly enough Greek to be of any help with the actual Greek word.